# Does it matter if I have 20 or one components with v-if in my page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Using either Vue/NuxtJS 2 or 3 I have the following situation. I now have modal components in TableViewRow components. Those modals are used to show an edit form for the row's data for example. This means the modal component exists x times, depending on the amount of rows shown. Can be 5, can be 100 times. Although I render them with `v-if`, wouldn't it be better to have one single modal on the table component itself and have a selectedROw value in the store to use to determine which one is selected?

Im asking this because of performance reasons. My assumption is that as long as `v-if` is `false`, it's not rendered and consuming no resources, but I'm unable to verify.

Comment: `My assumption is that as long as v-if is false,  it's not rendered and consuming no resources` thats correct. Although performance aside i'm not sure it would be the best approach, can't you just have one modal and handle all the differences via props in the nested component? if you posted some code it would be easier to provide suggestion

Answer (score -1):

Don't really understand who you code is **without an example**.

But based on your question, yes **you should avoid repetition** and manage one modal for all rows. It's **better and easiest to understand** for you or other developers.

And, **like you say** the `v-if` will not be rendered (if false), you can inspect your browser *HTML* and don't see the code. That's indeed true.

Nuxt generate static page **server-side**, so condition or not, the html will be full build to have the `v-if` maybe *true* or maybe *false*. The value can change anytime in the app and nuxt doesn't know about this. Nuxt need to build every case.

I'm not an expert on the subject, so maybe this will not affect (a lot) the rendered HTML, **but despite that i will say it's not a good way to achieve this and better to avoid it.**